# Bootstrap Vue table: show different details with each show details button in each row

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table in which a row would contain more than one "More Details" button, which when clicked expands to show additional information about the row. Basically, for the same row, if you click the first "More Details" button, I want to show information X and if the user clicks second "More Details" button, I want to show information Y.

```
    <template slot="iinstances" slot-scope="row">
      <div v-if=" total_rows>0 && row.item.imProdInstDet!=''">  <!-- The buttons are not displayed if the data is dummy -->
        <!-- Release Notes Button / Opens details row -->
        <b-button style="text-align: center" :variant="'primary'" @click.stop="row.toggleDetails" class="mr-1"> <!-- @click.stop prevents a 'row click' event -->
          {{row.item.imProdInstDet.length}}
        </b-button>
        <!---->
      </div>
    </template>

    <template slot="row-details" slot-scope="row">
      <div  style="float:left; width: 100%;">
        <pre>{{row.item.imProdInstDet}}</pre>
      </div>
    </template>

    <template slot="finstances" slot-scope="row">
      <!--          <div v-if=" total_rows>0 && row.item.notes!=''">  &lt;!&ndash; The buttons are not displayed if the data is dummy &ndash;&gt;-->
      <!-- Release Notes Button / Opens details row -->
      <b-button :variant="'primary'" @click.stop="row.toggleDetails" class="mr-1"> <!-- @click.stop prevents a 'row click' event -->
        More Details
      </b-button>
      <!---->
      <!--          </div>-->
    </template>

    <template slot="row-details" slot-scope="row">
      <div  style="float:left; width: 100%;">
        <pre>{{row.item.fiProdInstDet}}</pre>
      </div>
    </template>
```

This doesn't work. And if I comment out the last `row-details` template, then both the buttons show same information. Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't talk about it either. Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Edit:

```
      <b-table
        v-if="rows.length"
        :thead-tr-class="'report-thead'"
        :tbody-tr-class="'report-tbody'"
        :items="rows"
        :fields="columnsToDisplay"
        :sort-compare="sortTableByKey"
        :striped="true"
        :bordered="true"
        :outlined="true"
        :hover="true"
        :no-sort-reset="true"
        :show-empty="true"
        :filter="filter"
        @filtered="onFiltered"
        :empty-text="emptyText"
        :sort-desc="true"
        :caption-top="true"
        responsive>
    /b-table>
```

Comment: Are you using v-data-table? can you add the code where you define the table please?How are you trying to show more information? is it via popup?

Comment: @JavierHeisecke, I am using <b-table>, added code for the table. I am trying to show information in form of a dropdown (similar to here: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table) when you search for (Show Details) button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bootstrap-vue` is a versatile library. One solution could be:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      fields: ['first_name', 'last_name', 'show_details'],
      detailsMask: [],
      items: [{
          isActive: true,
          age: 40,
          first_name: 'Dickerson',
          last_name: 'Macdonald'
        },
        {
          isActive: false,
          age: 21,
          first_name: 'Larsen',
          last_name: 'Shaw'
        },
        {
          isActive: false,
          age: 89,
          first_name: 'Geneva',
          last_name: 'Wilson',
          // _showDetails: true
        },
        {
          isActive: true,
          age: 38,
          first_name: 'Jami',
          last_name: 'Carney'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleRowDetails(row, data) {
      this.detailsMask = data.split(', ')
      row.toggleDetails()
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!-- Load required Bootstrap and BootstrapVue CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />

<!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Load Vue followed by BootstrapVue -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load the following for BootstrapVueIcons support -->
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-container class="bv-example-row">
    <b-row>
      <b-col>
        <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields" striped responsive="sm">
          <template v-slot:cell(first_name)="row">
            {{ row.item.first_name }}
            <b-button size="sm" @click="toggleRowDetails(row, 'age, first_name')" class="mr-2">
              {{ row.detailsShowing ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} Age
            </b-button>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:cell(show_details)="row">
            <b-button size="sm" @click="toggleRowDetails(row, 'last_name')" class="mr-2">
              {{ row.detailsShowing ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} Details
            </b-button>
          </template>

          <template v-slot:row-details="row">
            <b-card>
              <b-row
                v-for="(detail, i) in detailsMask"
                :key="`detail-${i}`"
                class="mb-2"
              >
              <b-col
                sm="3"
                class="text-sm-rigth"
              >{{ detail }}: {{ row.item[detail] }}</b-col>
              </b-row>
            </b-card>
          </template>
        </b-table>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</div>
```

I just used the demo for https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#row-details-support and modified it a bit: passed the `row` and some `data` to a `method` and controlled the state from there. This way I could also set some display options on the details slot of the table, so I could show/hide the data from the objects displayed in the table.